# check text is present in table (selenium IDE)

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I am trying to check that the text "AUTOTEST" is present somewhere in my HTML table "tableTest".
In selenium IDE, i put this code :

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
    <td>//table[@id='tableTest']</td>
    <td>AUTOTEST</td>
</tr>
```

Here is the code of the HTML table :

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">AUTOTEST</a></td>
    <td>TEST</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">UOI</a></td>
    <td>TEST</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But the assertion always return false whereas text is well present in the table.
Which command can i use to check that text is present in my table ?

Comment: Please provide the HTML for the table you are trying to test as well as your selenium code. This will make answering a lot easier

Comment: @Jsmith2800 edit done

Comment: Are you using the wrong id?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for this is that you're trying to verify one bit of text using the entire table as a locator, rather than the specific section that contains the text you're looking for, as a result it isn't matching because you have other content within the table, and your verify step is looking for an exact match. You'd need to put in wildcards around AUTOTEST in your selenium script, that way it will just look to make sure that it is present somewhere within the table.

Script and log testing against the HTML code you provided for the table.

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>css=table</td>
    <td>*AUTOTEST*</td>
</tr>

[info] Playing test case Untitled
[info] Executing: |verifyText | css=table | *AUTOTEST* |
[info] Test case passed
```

Comment: Could you please adapt the code `css=table` to check the table where id=myTable ?

Answer (score 0):

VerifyTextPresent is depracted, VerifyText will do what you want:

```
<tr>
<td>verifyText</td>
<td>//table[@id='myTable']</td>
<td>*AUTOTEST*</td>
</tr>
```

The other thing to note is the text is the FULL text, so in this case you need to use a glob and use the * which serves as a wildcard.

Note: by the way you could also just specify the id (and not the full xpath) like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>myTable</td>
    <td>*AUTOTEST*</td>
</tr>
```